# Issue when Updating ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox that is editable by the user, so I bound the Text property to a property of my class. The ItemsSource of that same combobox is bound to an AsyncObservableCollection (which I did based on other posts and it works nicely).

However, I have a problem when updating the ItemsSource.

Here's the Steps to reproduce:

1. Select a value in the combobox drop down.
2. Type some text into the combobox. (say "aaa")
3. Update the ItemsSource. (via my button click)

Result: The MyText property remains set to the text you typed in ("aaa"), but the combo box shows a blank entry.

However, if you do the same steps above but skip Step 1, the combobox shows the text from the MyText property correctly. This leads me to believe that the selected index/selected value is being used to update the combobox after the update to the ItemsSource is done.

Any ideas on how I can keep the displayed value in sync with the MyText property after an update to the ItemsSource?

In the code provided below I'm updating the ItemsSource on the button click in order to reproduce.

Thank You!

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" IsEditable="True"
                          DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDataClass}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOptions}"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=MySelectedIndex}"
                          Text="{Binding Path=MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
              >
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,276,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class DataClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string mytext = "";
            public string MyText
            {
                get
                {
                    return mytext;
                }
                set
                {
                    mytext = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyText");
                }
            }

            private int myselectedindex = -1;
            public int MySelectedIndex 
            {
                get
                {
                    return myselectedindex;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value != -1)
                    {
                        mytext = MyListOptions[value];
                        OnPropertyChanged("MyText");
                    }
                }
            }

            private AsyncObservableCollection<string> mylistOptions = new AsyncObservableCollection<string>();
            public AsyncObservableCollection<string> MyListOptions
            {
                get
                {
                    return mylistOptions;
                }

                set
                {
                    mylistOptions.Clear();
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyListOptions");
                    foreach (string opt in value)
                    {
                        mylistOptions.Add(opt);
                    }
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyListOptions");
                }
            }

            public DataClass()
            {
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            internal void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        public DataClass MyDataClass { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            MyDataClass = new DataClass();

            MyDataClass.MyListOptions.Add("Option 1 - Provides helpful stuff.");
            MyDataClass.MyListOptions.Add("Option 2 - Provides more helpful stuff.");
            MyDataClass.MyListOptions.Add("Option 3 - Provides extra helpful stuff.");

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AsyncObservableCollection<string> newList = new AsyncObservableCollection<string>();
            newList.Add("Option A - Provides helpful stuff.");
            newList.Add("Option B - Provides more helpful stuff.");
            newList.Add("Option C - Provides extra helpful stuff.");

            MyDataClass.MyListOptions = newList;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem by binding the SelectedValue to the same property as Text and setting its mode to OneWay.

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" IsEditable="True"
                          DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDataClass}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOptions}"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=MySelectedIndex}"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyText, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Text="{Binding Path=MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
```